# How to send Friend Request or Like type notification using Laravel

Tags: php, notifications, facebook-like, laravel-5.3, laravel-notification

I am working on a social networking site project which was created with the Laravel Framework. I want to know how we can send a "Friend" request, "Like" or "Follow" kind of notification using Laravel.

I am new to this framework, and would appreciate some guidance. I am not expecting source code but general hints or suggestions would help me a lot.